# Flex 4 Label and Selection

Tags: text, label, flex4, selection, flex-spark

I am displaying data in spark Labels. Now I find that the user cannot select and copy the displayed text. The docs don't show what needs to be done (mx.Label allowed this but a spark label does not).

So what's the solution? How can I allow users to select and copy data displayed on my screen?

Answer (score 11):

Only :

1. RichEditableText
2. TextInput
3. TextArea

allow text selection in Flex 4.

See here : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS02f7d8d4857b1677-165a04e1126951a2d98-7fe4.html

Comment: Yes - but I dont want to use these mentioned above to display data. I want to use Labels as the Look and Feel of the Label is desired here and not the L&F of a TextXXX.

Comment: Why not changing the look and feel of selectable components so they look like the Label?

Comment: There's still problems with this.  The RichEditableText/TextInput components don't support maxDisplayedLines and showTruncationTip that makes the Spark Label appealing... but alas, no text selection (still) on Spark Label

Answer (score 0):

Use `<mx:Text>` instead.
It looks just like a Label but allows you to copy from it.